# Перенос вывода команды в bash

Tags: linux, bash

Вечер добрый. Пишу командный
скрипт, позволяющий подробно описать(логгировать) процесс упаковки в некий файл отладки. Так вот у меня идет вывод все в одну строчку, не очень удобно читать. Где нужно поставить /n?

```
    #!bin/bash
    exec 1>log.txt
    date=`date`
    echo $date
    echo  -e `zip -r devops.zip ~/Desktop/DevOps`
    echo "Zip file created successfully"
```

Вывод идет такой

```
неділя, 9 липня 2017 19:08:47 +0300
adding: home/sergey/Desktop/DevOps/ (stored 0%) adding: home/sergey/Desktop/DevOps/networks/ (stored 0%) adding: home/sergey/Desktop/DevOps/networks
```

1) Где нужно исправить чтобы по adding с новой строчки выводило?
2) Что еще можно добавить в скрипт для более глубокого описания лога?

Comment: как открываете log.txt ?

Comment: попробуйте еще `zip -r -ll`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor открываю обычно nano,vim,vi,gedit, emacs log.txt

Comment: А зачем тут вообще echo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорим о bash, я в логировании стараюсь избегать *echo*. Есть *printf* с более расширенными возможностями.

Я бы посоветовал вариант с tar, очень много боли испытал работая с zip, так как по умолчанию его не ставят на сервера, tar и gzip стандарт.

```
tar -czf /path/to/devops.tar.gz /home/developer/DevOps &&
printf "[%s]: %s %s\n" "$(date)" "Backup complited for " "$(du /home/developer/devops.tar.gz"  >> /path/to/backup.log
```

В логе получим

```
~$ cat backup.log
[Sun Jul  9 20:46:57 BST 2017]: Backup complited for  342  ./devops.tar.gz
[Sun Jul  9 20:47:01 BST 2017]: Backup complited for  352  ./devops.tar.gz
[Sun Jul  9 20:47:39 BST 2017]: Backup complited for  362  ./devops.tar.gz
[Sun Jul  9 20:47:54 BST 2017]: Backup complited for  372  ./devops.tar.gz
[Sun Jul  9 20:48:08 BST 2017]: Backup complited for  382  ./devops.tar.gz
```

Так же tar поддерживает обновления архива только измененными файлами. Читайте обширную документацию.

```
&& - выполнить последующую команду, если первая завершилась успешно (0)
%s - форматирование вывода, воспринимать как текст
$() равно `` сабпроцесс,  но более читаемый.
```

Если переносимость на винду критична (в ma. tar и gzip стоят по дифолту), замените tar на zip или rar в первой строчке.

Для отказоустойчивости, добавил бы проверку на наличие сохраняемых файлов и прямой путь до места самого архива. В лог бы добавил размер конечного архива и его sha256sum.

---

Дополнение 15/07/17

`` - обратные овычки
'' -  одинарные

Из man bash версии 4.4.12:

```
Command Substitution
    Command substitution allows 
the  output of a command to replace
the command name.

There are two forms:
    $(command)
or
    `command`
```

пример

```
~$ date=`date`
~$ echo $date
Sat Jul 15 06:05:35 BST 2017
~$ echo -e `date`
Sat Jul 15 06:07:00 BST 2017
~$ date=$(date)
~$ echo $date
Sat Jul 15 06:07:40 BST 2017
```

Ссылки

- https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708569/3295105

Comment: `$()` не равно `\`\`` в пределах синтаксического парсера (пара моментов как минимум есть).

Comment: @0andriy был бы рад примеру и ссылкам. Дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: Запустите `echo '\\'` как подкоманду в обоих случаях, посмотрите на результат.

Comment: @0andriy у меня всегда shellcheck включен в Emacs  на "echo `\\`" сразу выдал предупреждения: SC1073 и SC1009 можете глянуть на странице разработчика. В POSIX рекомендуют использовать $() для саббпроцессов. Я не могу говорить за остальные оболочки и Bash ниже v4 т.к. не пользовался плотно.

Comment: У вас написано не то, о чём я толкую.

Comment: @0andriy "...в Emacs на "echo `\`..." SO съел бэкслаш., \\ это должно было быть. Заметил по другим вашим комментариях, вы отвлечетесь излишней загадочностью в своих суждениях :)

Comment: Спасибо за психологический портрет меня, и ещё раз внимательно прочитайте мой второй комментарий здесь. Вы, по-моему, не очень внимательны сегодня. (И понимате, если я вам расскажу всё в деталях, то вы ничему не научитесь, а это не моя цель)

Comment: @0andriy В случае использования $() выдает \\, а при использовании обратных кавычек, только  один \. Вы это имели в виду?

Comment: Именно! Это был второй аспект. Первый очень похож, не совсем про это -- про вложенность вызовов. Оба аспекта взаимосвязаны как я понимаю, хотя мне лень копаться в исходниках, например, `dash`, чтобы быть на 100% уверенным.

Answer (score 3):

в одну строку вывод программы *zip* превращает передача этого вывода встроенной команде *echo*. попробуйте просто вызывать программу. т.е. вместо:

```
echo  -e `zip -r devops.zip ~/Desktop/DevOps`
```

напишите:

```
zip -r devops.zip ~/Desktop/DevOps
```

---

к слову. возможно, переменную `date` вы запланировали использовать позже, но если нет, то уберите лишние переливания из пустого в порожнее — вместо:

```
date=`date`
echo $date
```

напишите просто вызов программы:

```
date
```